# java.lang.NullPointerException: throw with null exception in Release Build

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm getting this issue in only release builds but running perfectly in debug
    anyone know this issue ?

```
 Process: com.truqit.customer, PID: 5365
    java.lang.NullPointerException: throw with null exception
        at com.truqit.customer.authentication.a.a.a()
        at com.truqit.customer.authentication.c.a()
        at i.n.run()
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802)
```

Comment: Please add the code that produces that error.

Comment: @AlexMamo Sorry not able edit code so I'm sharing Link https://drive.google.com/open?id=12AJD56ogzf-aP7yF-oRmfacau77MH5kN

Comment: when this issue occured? 
1. on screen load
2. on button click or on some other action

Comment: @Rakesh On button Click    case R.id.login_button

Comment: @Rakesh, In my case it happens when page loads. Do you have any solution for that? Please let me know. Thanks